# My birthday paradox event simulator in javascript is not working well

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, random, birthday-paradox

I tried to do a in Javascript a birthday paradox event for 23 students, it should give me an average probability of 51% but it always give me number around 67%. Here the code:

```
var pers = [];
var D = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < 23; k++) {
        pers.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*366) + 1));
    }
    var npers = pers.slice();
    npers.sort();
    for ( var v = 0; v < npers.length; v++ ) {
        if (npers[v-1] == npers[v]) {
            D++;
        }
    }
    pers = [];
}
D = D / 100;
var DD = D.toString(); 
DD = DD + "%";
document.write(DD);
```

Could you,please, tell me where I committed a mistake ? Thank you very much. I'm sure that I've committed a mistake because the lowest percentage that I got was 66%, well over the 51% goal. (I've ran it several times). Thank you again for your help, it's been hours that I'm trying to figure out what I got wrong but I can't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You count the number of *all coincidences*, not *the number of cases where there are at least one coincidence in the room*. That is, if on a given set there are, say, three people such that they share a birthday, or two pairs of people sharing birthdays, you increment `D` twice.

Add a `break;` after `D++;` and you'll get numbers around 50%.

By the way, your `v` loop underindexes `npers` (at `v=0`, you compare `npers[-1]` against `npers[0]`) - but that does not affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this for-loop

```
for ( var v = 0; v < npers.length; v++ ) {
    if (npers[v-1] == npers[v]) {
        D++;
    }
}
```

This will increment D (the number of successes) for every pair within a trial instead of just increment it once when you find a pair. You only care about the existence of a pair. Inserting a `break;` after `D++;` should solve this.